# Microsoft .NET Charting components break doing a Simple Moving Average on a Stock chart

Tags: c#, charts, .net-4.5

I creating a simple Microsoft Forms application that will display a stock chart using the Microsoft .Net Chart Controls Library.  I can successfully display the stock action using LINQ to SQL:

```
IEnumerable<Quote> quotes = Store.Quotes.Where(q => q.Ticker == "MSFT" && q.Date > DateTime.Parse("7/01/2013"));
MainChart.Series["SeriesTop"].Points.Clear();
MainChart.Series["SeriesTop"].Points.DataBindXY(quotes, "Date", quotes, "Low,High,Open,Close");
MainChart.Series["SeriesTop"].LegendText = quotes.First().Ticker;
```

However if I add a Simple Moving average I get a big red X instead of a Chart, no exception or other message that would help.  This is the line of code that breaks it:

```
MainChart.DataManipulator.FinancialFormula(FinancialFormula.MovingAverage, "5", "SeriesTop", "AvgTop");
```

I use visual studio to examine the contents of the "AvgTop" series it looks ok to me, but the chart won't display.

Thanks,
Ken

Comment: The big red X *is* an exception, it just happens to be caught and handled.  Use Debug + Exceptions and tick the Thrown checkbox for CLR exceptions so the debugger stops when it is thrown.  The call stack ought to provide some insight.

Comment: I also had to go into Tools > Options > Debug and uncheck "Enable Just My Code" but after doing that I was able to see the exception message: Series 'SeriesTop' and Series 'AvgTop' must be aligned to perform the operation. The series currently have a different number of data points.

Comment: Kudos, that's the Real Programmer option.

Answer (score 1):

I played around with DataManipulator.InsertEmptyPoints (as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456677.aspx) and the big red X went away but the the weekends got filled with empty data and I didn't want that, I wanted the weekends (and other non-trading days) to disappear from the graph (see `Series.IsXValueIndexed = true`).  So I rolled my own method to align the two data series:

```
    public static void AlignSeries(Series seriesA, Series seriesB)
    {
        var aligned = seriesA.Points.GroupJoin(seriesB.Points, a => a.XValue, b => b.XValue, (a, b) => new { a = a, b = b.SingleOrDefault() }).ToArray();
        DataPointCollection bCollection = seriesB.Points;
        bCollection.Clear();
        foreach (var pair in aligned)
        {
            DataPoint bPoint = new DataPoint();
            bPoint.XValue = pair.a.XValue;
            if (null != pair.b)
            {
                bPoint.YValues = pair.b.YValues;
            }
            else
            {
                bPoint.IsEmpty = true;
            }
            bCollection.Add(bPoint);
        }
    }
```

I would certainly hope that someone with more wisdom than me could recommend a better approach or an API call that I missed.